# Cannot update Excel 2004 to more advanced version (the software is part of the Microsoft 365 family plan)

Tags: microsoft-excel

I am using Windows 10 professional, 64-bit operating system. (just to be considered as a factor that may cause this problem)

While trying to fix this problem, I uninstalled and installed the Office software many times.

I downloaded individual installation and updating packages for Excel 2016 and Excel 2006, tried to install the software both online and offline and also tried both of the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version. My current excel version is displayed as Excel 2004.

However, none of these methods helped. What may cause this problem and how can I solve it?

[image]
[image]
[image]

Problem solved, I posted an answer to my own question, didn't quite solve the updating problem but indeed dragged me out of my plight. Thank you all so much, your answers helped me a lot.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> I downloaded individual installation and updating packages for Excel 2016 and Excel 2006, tried to install the software both online and offline and also tried both of the 32-bit version and the 64-bit version. My current excel version is displayed as Excel 2004.

You already have the current version of Office 365 already installed.

[image]

**In order to install Build 12827.20160 (Version 2005), you would have to switch your release channel to `Monthly Channel (Targeted)`, but that should only be done with the approval of your Administrator.**

[image]

**In order to install Build 12905.20000 (Version 2006), you would have to switch your release channel to `Insider`, but that should only be done with the approval of your Administrator.**

[image]

> I thought the most current version for excel should be the version "Excel 2016", and my superior is using the version "Excel 2006". there are some add-ins that work for him but not for me.

Office 2019 and Office 2016 are perpetual installations of Office.  Office 365 receives monthly updates while Office 2019 and Office 2016 only receive security updates.

**Excel `Version 2004` is a specific build of Excel 365 and requires an active Office 365 subscription.**  The current perpetual license version is Office 2019, not Office 2016.

**It's important to point out that retail installations of Office 2016 and Office 2019 have their own version of Build 12730.20270 (Version 2004).**  While they share the same build number as the respected Office 365 build, they are not identical, since Office 2016 and Office 2019 perpetual installations only receive security updates.

Source:

- [How to update Office 2016 to Office 2019?](https://superuser.com/questions/1366095/how-to-update-office-2016-to-office-2019)
- [Update Features of MS Office 2016](https://superuser.com/questions/1468243/update-features-of-ms-office-2016/1468247#1468247)
- [Retail versions of Office 2016 C2R and Office 2019](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/update-history-office-2019)

> What may cause this problem and how can I solve it?

**You need a valid Office 365 subscription in order to update your Office 365 installation to the current version released on May 14th.**

If you are unable to update the installation to **Build 12827.20160** that would be an indication you don't have an active Office 365 subscription.  If you want to install `Version 2005` or `Version 2006` that requires opting into the Office Insider program within Excel.

Source: [Release Notes for Office Monthly Channel (Targeted)](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/officeupdates/release-notes-monthly-channel-targeted)

Comment: Thank you so much for answering my question, your answer helped me realized how the version number is different from the build number, as well as gave me a hint for how to match the build number but not the version number, to the current update for excel.

Answer (score 0):

As Microsoft 365 has different update channels, the update pace is different for each update channel.

For Monthly Channel, although Version 2005 would come, Version 2004 (Build 12730.20270) is still the latest officially released version now. So it is why you could not update Microsoft 365 to more advanced versions.

To update Microsoft 365 to [Version 2006 (Build 12905.20000)](https://insider.office.com/en-us/releasenotes/pc/fast) currently, please [join the Office Insider for PC](https://insider.office.com/en-us/join), let Office leaves Monthly Channel.

Joining Office Insider program, it means before most of the people, you will get preview builds for the latest updates and fixes that Microsoft releases.

Answer (score 0):

Thank you all for reading and answering this question! I eventually solved my problem by upgrading my operation system.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/T1guV.jpg)

depends on the version of operatinng system, the excel software opens add-ins in different browsers. 
[list of the browsers used by each windows version](https://i.stack.imgur.com/VlyKC.jpg)

For last version I used, which was the "windows 10 professional, version 1803", IE11 was the default browser used to open add-ins. After I upgrade it to the version 1903, its default browser became to edge^2 browser, which is more up to date.

This did not help me to upgrade my Excel version, but indeed helped me to improve my experience with Excel. It allowed me to have access to more advanced and larger amount of Excel add-ins. For the current time, this gives me enough supports to finish my stagnant work.

I learned that not only the version of Excel can affect our using experience, but other factors should also be considered as important elements.

Thank you all once again! Hopefully this discussion can help more people by chance.

Comment: What does updating Windows have to do with Excel?